# Wordpress password how to compare user password to wordpress user table password?

Tags: php, wordpress

### Custom Register user

wp_create_user (works)

```
    $username='balan';
    $user_pass ='balan';
    $user_email= 'random_email@email.com';
    $password = wp_hash_password( $user_pass );
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $password, $user_email );
```

### Custom Login user

```
    $username='balan';
    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
    $pass ='balan';
    $hash = wp_hash_password($pass);
    if (wp_check_password( $pass, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID ) ) {
        echo "<br>Correct";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Wrong";
    }
    **WordPress login function** 
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = 'balan';
    $creds['user_password'] ='balan';
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

I get error when comparing login password. How to compare login password?
`wp_check_password()` is not working. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please use "$user_pass ='balan';" as password in $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $password, $user_email ); don't use  " $password = wp_hash_password( $user_pass );"

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password

Comment: What is the error upon using wp_check_password() ?

Comment: Try printing $user; and let me know

Comment: Check my edited answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compare an already hashed password with its plain-text string, Here is the example.

```
<?php
$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

$password_hashed = '$P$B55D6LjfHDkINU5wF.v2BuuzO0/XPk/';
$plain_password = 'test';

if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword($plain_password, $password_hashed)) {
    echo "YES, Matched";
} else {
    echo "No, Wrong Password";
}
?>
```

I guess instead of `$user->data->user_pass` you need to use `$user->user_pass;` as per the documentation here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/

I am only guessing because I don't know what `print_r($user);` returns

Hope it helps !

Comment: `wp_check_password( $pass, $user->user_pass, $user->ID )` It will return empty. But `$user->user_pass` value is same as db password....

Comment: Isn't it working by using wp_check_password( $pass, $user->user_pass, $user->ID );  ??

Comment: if it returns empty it means passwords don't match

Comment: How can I create an API for this code, I'll pass hash and plain text then it will return true or false

Answer (score 1):

`wp_create_user` calls `wp_insert_user` which uses `wp_hash_password` internally.

In essence with your code you end up with

```
 wp_hash_password(wp_hash_password('balan'));
```

`wp_create_user` should be provided with the raw password.

Comment: Did you try rewriting the user create to
$username='balan';
    $user_pass ='balan';
    $user_email= 'random_email@email.com';
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $user_pass , $user_email );
deleting the user, creating it again with the changed create user code
if so please post the error message